# recursive function calling itself even condition is satisfied

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a very simple code here which uses recursion to iterate the queue class i need to simple print 6 on screen but it print 1 ,please tell me where i am wrong.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    q.Enqueue(1);
    q.Enqueue(2);
    q.Enqueue(3);
    q.Enqueue(4);
    q.Enqueue(5);
    q.Enqueue(6);

    long id = getID(Convert.ToInt64(q.Dequeue()));

    Response.Write(id);  

}

private long getID(long id)
{
    if (id == 6)
    {
        return id;
    }
    else
    {

        id = Convert.ToInt64(q.Dequeue());

        if (q.Count != 0)
        {
            getID(id);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    return id;
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest putting a breakpoint at the start of your code and stepping through each line at a time to understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if (q.Count != 0)
{
    getID(id);
}
```

with

```
if (q.Count != 0)
{
    return getID(id);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are missing a return:

```
    if (q.Count != 0)
    {
        return getID(id);  // Here
    }
```

Currently your code calls `getID` but simply discards the result. Then when control reaches the end of the method it returns `id`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything with the return value of the recursive call, so your top-level `getID` will simply return its parameter when it hits the bottom.

Try `return getID(id)` in the `if` test.